# In excel get the folder's created time

Tags: excel, vba

how to get folder's created time in Excel?

I know

```
FileDateTime(FileOrFoldername)
```

can retrive  a time, but that is the "created or last modified date"; also

```
Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FileCreatedAt = oFS.GetFile(PathWithFilename).DateCreated
```

could retrieve the file created time, but this does not work for a folder.

Comment: Try: `FileCreatedAt = oFS.GetFolder(PathWithFilename).DateCreated`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following sub to get folder created date and time

```
Sub DirDate()
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fld As Scripting.Folder
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder("c:\windows")
    MsgBox fld.DateCreated
End Sub
```

> You have to active the Microsoft Scripting Runtime in references. See below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This should help you:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder(PathName)
ShowDateCreated = f.DateCreated
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c87day3(v=vs.84).aspx